# How to register two net service names in local_listener parameter

Tags: oracle

I'm configuring data guard. I want to register the local_listener parameter with two tnsnames: **tnsname1** and **tnsname2**.

I use `ALTER SYSTEM SET LOCAL_LISTENER='tnsname1','tnsname2';

but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do here. The LOCAL_LISTENER parameter defines an oracle listener or list of listeners, typically defined in your tnsnames.ora file, that your instance should register with. For example:

```
my_listeners=
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1)(PORT=1521))
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1)(PORT=1522))
    )
```

This means you have two listeners running on your local server, one at port 1521 and the other at 1522. Use:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET LOCAL_LISTENER=my_listeners
```

to register your database with those two listeners. I don't think you can specify multiple tnsnames entries in the command.

Answer (score 2):

ALTER SYSTEM SET LOCAL_LISTENER='tnsname1';

Then in the tnsnames.ora file configure two listeners for that name.

tnsname1 =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host1)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host1)(PORT = 6000))
  )

If the listeners are not local use
ALTER SYSTEM SET REMOTE_LISTENER='tnsname2';

tnsname2 =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host2)(PORT = 3000))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host3)(PORT = 4000))
  )

Comment: Saved my life. Thanks. How do I persist this LOCAL_LISTENER between Oracle service restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this one is correct:
alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER="(ADDRESS_LIST=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.1)(PORT=1521))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.2)(PORT=1526)))";

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault.  Can you edit your answer to explain how it is different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

ALTER SYSTEM SET local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=name1)(PORT=1521))','(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=name2)(PORT=1523))' SCOPE=BOTH;

LOCAL_LISTENER is a comma-delimited list parameter. If a comma appears in the string, then the entire string must be enclosed in double quotation marks. Set the LOCAL_LISTENER parameter as follows:

ALTER SYSTEM SET LOCAL LISTENER=["]listener_address["][,...];
For example, if the listener address "ab,cd" is entered, then it resolves to one listener address. If the address is entered as ab,cd, then it resolves to two listener addresses, ab and cd.

From: Oracle® Database Net Services Administrator's Guide
11g Release 2 (11.2)
Part Number E10836-05

Registering Information with a Local Listener

Answer (score -2):

Here you go:

alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= )(PORT=)),(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= )(PORT=))' scope=both;

Ex:
alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= 192.168.1.1)(PORT=1521)),(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST= 192.168.1.2)(PORT=1526))' scope=both;

Comment: you can delete your own answers.  Or just edit them so they are better.